# angular6 - Send data from one component to another

Tags: components, share, angular6, between

- I want to send the response after the creation of the ticket to the component that shows ticket details, I am fairly new with angular 6 so I need some advice.
- What is the best way to send the response from the service? 
  Send it to component  and then to component for details or somehow can I send it to componnet that is responsible for the detail?
- Shared service I heard about that ,so maybe that or also I heard about   some parent child method but I did not understand that quite, as now between the two component is no relation ( no parent child I think)

[image]

Comment: Share your data by using `ticket.service.ts` so after response you can hold your data in your service and then use it to show ticket details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically to possible approach:

**Parent - Child communication**

You can obtain this functionality with the help of the `@Input` annotation. So the parent component hold the data object and pass it to the child component. Then you can manage data updates with `OnChanges` interface.

You could prefer this approach if you want to enphasize parent - children relation between your components. By this way you are forcing your child component to be inside another component managing original data.
By this way the data are destroyed when parent is destroyed.

**Shared Service**

This approach, that is the one you described, is based on a shared service that hold data and serves it to the subscribers. So the service manage and hold the data and a potentially illimited number of component can access that data.

This approach works with [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), so yours component have to observe for data updates.

By this way the data are destroyed when the service is destroyed, or better when all the component that hold an istance of the service are destroyed.

--

Looking at your diagram what you should do for me is:

- CreateComponent asks to Service to create a ticket
- The Service create the ticket and send back new ticket data to the CreateComponent
- Che CreateComponent read new obtained data and IF the creation is successful request a route navigation to the TicketDetail. Otherwise you can manage eventual errors

If you go to detail directly from Service you can't correctly manage creation outcome, because in the Service you have not a view to interact with user. Maybe you could find some way to do this, but I think that it could be a little bit difficult